# Finding the Average Value of the derivative of a function.

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

The question is from an old AP Calculus test. 
According to the answer key, the correct answer is D. However, I can't understand why the average value of $f'$ must be equal to $\frac 5 2$. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the fundamental theorem of calculus. The average value of a (sufficiently nice) function $g$ on the interval $[a,b]$ is $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b g(x)\,dx$$

In this case, the function is $f'(x)$, and the interval is $[1,3]$. Since the $f$ is twice differentiable, its derivative is continuous, so we can use the fundamental theorem of calculus. The average value is $$\frac{1}{2}\int_1^3f'(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}(f(3)-f(1))=\frac{5}{2}.$$